# Birds eye view dashboard on Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

Is it possible to create a dashboard that looks similar to the one below (metrics inventory under observability)
[image: Looking for this kind of dashboard]

Is it actually possible using Vega? When I tried to create not perform as good as the one in observability as its much more interactive. I am trying to get a visualization where users could see pod distribution across the nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tried to investigate on this but could not find a solution. It could be done using heat maps but does not look similar to image I shared.